# How can I use XML as a data source in WebAPI .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having some problems with my WebAPI. I have followed the guide from Microsoft and it works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api?fbclid=IwAR0tEMDMX3URn2YO0pwnTTAbY2RuGkdu-HUobznac4Lwus6rOVPSeiX-lFs

Now I want to be able to get data from my XML file instead of the hardcoded values the guide use. I have tried to search for this already but not sure I find the right thing. How can I do this?

**Code I have tried:**

```
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetAllProducts()
    {

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\products.xml");

    foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Catalog")

        .Descendants("Product"))

    {

        Product product = new Product();

        product.Id = element.Element("Id").Value;
        product.Name = element.Element("Name").Value;
        product.Category = element.Element("Category").Value;
        product.Added_Date = element.Element("Added_Date").Value;//this will not work because its not a string
        product.Price = element.Element("Price").Value;//this will not work because its not a string

        products.Add(product);

        }

        return products;
    }
```

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <product id="P1">
      <name>Royal Gala</name>
      <category>Apple</category>
      <country>New Zeeland</country>
      <price>33.00</price>
      <added_date>2011-01-11</added_date>
      <description>This is a lovely red apple.</description>
   </product>
   <product id="P2">
      <name>Granny Smith</name>
      <category>Apple</category>
      <country>Australia</country>
      <price>33.00</price>
      <added_date>2013-12-25</added_date>
      <description>This is a lovely green apple.</description>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to parse `string` to a specific type

```
Product product = new Product();
//..
product.Added_Date = DateTime.Parse(element.Element("Added_Date").Value);
product.Price = double.Parse(element.Element("Price").Value); //or float, or decimal
```

And consider using `Elements` method instead of `Descendants` cause last one returns all children and their inner children and so on and `Elements` returns first level children

```
var productNodes = doc.Root.Elements("product"); //note this is case sensitive
foreach (XElement element in productNodes) {
    Product product = new Product();
    //..
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this was a side problem. I cannot get it to work at all.

Comment: It is working if I use this:

      **Product[] products = new Product[] 
        { 
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }... blabla
        };**

If I use the code I had in my post it doesn't show anything and also says NullReferenceException.

Comment: It still says the same as before: **"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred"**

Comment: @Jacob on which line an exception does occur?

Comment: book.Id = element.Element("Id").Value;
and if I remove it it will be error on next row and countinuing

Comment: @Jacob Ah, you need to use lowercase there, as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Ops. I forgot to change this. However, the same happens in lower case.

Comment: It worked now when I removed the id, is it something wiered with it because it says book id=""?

Comment: @Jacob That's because there is no `id` element in you xml, it is an attribute. So do this `product.Id = element.Attribute("id").Value;`

Comment: I did not try all the side problems. The date is working, the price is not. It says format exception. Can it be because the XML is using dot and not comma?

Comment: @Jacob Yea, might be. Use this `double.Parse(element.Element("price").Value, new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "." });`